# outlook.com on thunderbird using IMAP only without using pop3 - > GMAIL -> IMAP technique

Tags: thunderbird, imap, email-client, pop3

After lot of attempt I found one username which is simple on outlook.com. so was wondering is there any way using any workaround to access outlook.com using IMAP on thunderbird. Currently I have POP3 enabled in my thunderbird but there are lots of problems with POP3 so wanted to ask this.

I found lot of articles but they all say it does not support, but is there any workaround so that at least there is syncing between thunderbird and outlook.com server for the folder and messages I delete.

I also read the they will support IMAP later they do support EAS some new better way by which you can not only sync your mails, but also contacts, tasks, calender etc.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry to disappoint you but the situation is that Outlook.com does not provide support for mail synchronisation via the IMAP protocol.  There are no workarounds for this.

Microsoft have said that it WILL come eventually, but it is a low priority for them.

Thunderbird does not provide a method of retrieving and synching mail (or anything else) via Exchange Active Synch protocol.

You can either use POP3, which makes life awkward if you get your mail on more than one device, or do what I do and use the Outlook.com web interface for your main mail/calendar/people application.

It's not ideal, I know, but it's the best you can do if you want to use live mail currently.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you're just concerned about the email address.

If you want to keep this email address while enjoying the convenience of an IMAP account, simply create an email account with a provider that does support IMAP and set up automatic forwarding in your outlook.com interface.

(I will do that until Microsoft figures out they actually should listen to what a lot of people say when trying to improve their service.)